# How to import just the functions i need and tree shake

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, date-fns

I am trying to import 2 functions from date-fns (using webpack 4 and babel). 
When I analyze my **prod** build the whole library is added to the bundle.

First I have tried importing with `import { format, max } from 'date-fns';` and  setting "module" to false in Babel's presets `@babel/preset-env`, since Webpack doc says this could hinder treeshaking.

Also tried importing by `import max from 'date-fns/max';`

I expected Webpack to be able to remove all functions but the imported ones, since modularity is one of `date-fns` selling points. 
Can´t think of what I am doing wrong at the moment.

Could someone please share their experience or solutions for this?

Adding 170kb for using two functions is not acceptable.

Comment: Checked my package.json and found i was running a version <2.
Only v2.x provides support for ECMAScript Modules:
https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/master/docs/esm.md